# Query table with 2 repeated fields

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a schema that contains multiple repeated fields which are all record type. For example, the schema is like this:

```
name: string,

class: record(repeated),

class.id :string

class.title: string,

school: record(repeated),

school.id: string,

school.title: string.
```

How can I query in standard SQL and return a student row with a list of class and school (class and school are totally unrelated).

Actually, a simple SELECT * works, but I want to select each column and rename them, i.e. SELECT name as student_name, classes, schools. I also want to filter some of the class and school, i.e. only show classes that satisfy some constraints.

Example: name: 'Tom', class: [{id: 1, title: math}, {id: 2, title: physics}, {id: 3, title: math}], school: [{id: 1, title: Yale}, {id: 2, title: Havard}, {id: 3, title: Yale}]
I want to filter by class.title and school.title to return a row like this: name: 'Tom', class: [{id: 1, title: math}, {id: 3, title: math}], school: [{id: 1, title: Yale}, {id: 3, title: Yale}]

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Please show some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT name as student_name, 
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM UNNEST(class) class WHERE class.title = 'math') classes,
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM UNNEST(school) school WHERE school.title = 'Yale') schools
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
```

You can test / play with above using dummy data from your question:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable` AS (
  SELECT 
    'Tom' name, 
    [
      STRUCT(1 AS id, 'math' AS title), 
      (2, 'physics'), 
      (3, 'math')
    ] class, 
    [
      STRUCT(1 AS id, 'Yale' AS title), 
      (2, 'Havard'), 
      (3, 'Yale')
    ] school 
)
SELECT name as student_name, 
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM UNNEST(class) class WHERE class.title = 'math') classes,
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM UNNEST(school) school WHERE school.title = 'Yale') schools
FROM `yourproject.yourdataset.yourtable`
```

with result as below

```sql
name    class.id    class.title school.id   school.title     
Tom     1           math        1           Yale     
        3           math        3           Yale
```

Above should give you an idea on how to filter inside the repeated field